# Seeking tutorials about GIS workflows in FME?

Tags: fme-form, references

I have never used FME for spatial processes before. However, I would like to use it in automating some GIS processes and learn.

Are there are any specific tutorials that explain this?

Answer (score 2):

The vast majority of FME workflows are spatial - it's what it is designed for.  For more specific assistance I recommend giving further detail of the kind of process you want to learn.

Safe Software have all sorts of resources for training, including videos and webinars.  See the training section here: https://www.safe.com/training/live-online/

There is also:

- [FME Knowledge Center](https://knowledge.safe.com/index.html)
- [FME Transformer Gallery](https://www.safe.com/transformers/)